# Haskell - Ambiguous type variable, why?

Tags: haskell, types

Why does the following compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class IsList a where
  isList :: a -> Bool

instance IsList a where
  isList x = False

instance IsList [a] where
  isList x = True

main = print (isList 'a') >> print (isList ['a'])
```

But changing `main` to [this](http://ideone.com/ldZYbV):

```
main = print (isList 42) >> print (isList [42])
```

Gives the following error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Num a0) arising from the literal `42' at prog.hs:13:22-23
  (IsList a0) arising from a use of `isList' at prog.hs:13:15-20
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the first argument of `isList', namely `42'
In the first argument of `print', namely `(isList 42)'
In the first argument of `(>>)', namely `print (isList 42)'
```

`isList` surely isn't in the `Num` class is it? And if not, why the ambiguity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is not with isList but with the constant 42.  The constant 'a' has a concrete type of Char.  The constant 42 does not have a concrete type.

```
ghci> :t 42
42 :: Num a => a
```

The compiler needs a concrete type.  It will work if you change main to the following:

```
main = print (isList (42 :: Int)) >> print (isList [42 :: Int])
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense. It can compile if it doesn't know its type. But why doesn't "defaulting" work here? Why not default to Integer?

Comment: The compiler doesn't have anything indicating that it should treat that as an Int.  If the same identifier was...say...passed into a function that needed an Int, then the type would be unified to Int.  But it's not going to make that assumption for you automatically.

Comment: @Clinton: Defaulting is only done if all the constraints only refer to standard classes. `IsList` is not a standard class. This requirement can be relaxed with `ExtendedDefaultRules`.